# SQL - CURSOR not fetching values properly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm new to cursors so I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly but I'm trying to loop thru a temp table foreach row and compute the value for Column_Y using Column_X and another value from a variable. The variable value is correct but I'm not getting the values for Column_X from the cursor. See below:

**SQL:**

```
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @val DECIMAL
DECLARE @percent DECIMAL

DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT a.Id, a.Val FROM #Temp_Tbl a

OPEN my_cursor

FETCH FROM my_cursor INTO @id, @val

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 --@Total is of type DECIMAL & is populated previously
 PRINT Convert(varchar,@id) + ': (' + Convert(varchar,@val) + '/' + Convert(varchar,@Total) + '),'
 SELECT @percent = @val / @Total
 UPDATE #Temp_Tbl SET PERCENT_OF = @percent WHERE Id = @id
 FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @id, @val
END

CLOSE my_cursor
DEALLOCATE my_cursor
```

**RESULTS:**

```
| ID | Val | PERCENT_OF |
| 1  | 25  | 1          |
| 2  | 45  | 0          |
| 3  | 30  | 0          |
```

**Messages Output:**

```
2: (1/200) --NOTE: It's not printing the first record but 1 does get updated in the
3: (0/200) --PERCENT_OF column in the first row & 0 in the second.
```

Can anyone tell where I'm going wrong here? Thanks for any help.

Comment: in a query prior to the cursor. `@Total` is being populated correctly bc my 'Print' messages have the correct value for `@Total`.

Comment: What type of numbers are stored in column `PERCENT_OF`? Decimal or integer?

Comment: If you are new to Cursors, then I would encourage you to stay new to them.  Set-oriented SQL is much preferred and usually both simpler and faster.  In your example above, the whole thing can be reduced to one (much faster) statement.

Comment: how can it be reduced to one statement? I've heard that cursors were slow and would much prefer an alternative route

Comment: @RBarryYoung +1. I reduced it down to one update statement. No idea why that didn't cross my mind initially. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `DECIMAL` without telling it the precision and scale. How many decimals do you want?. You should **always** explicitly use the precision and scale. Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @val DECIMAL(16,4)
DECLARE @percent DECIMAL(16,4)
```

Comment: Turns out my `PERCENT_OF` column was not declared with precision & scale causing the issue. Thanks for the help.